# how can I replace one single element in an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby

how can I replace one single element in an array in ruby? so that an array

```
days=["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "jueves"]  #so "jueves" gets replaced by the string "thursday"
```

thanks

Comment: You mean like: `days[3] = 'thurdsay'`?

Comment: @pguardiario, I've noticed that's an increasingly popular spelling of the day of the week following 'wednesday'.

Answer (score 5):

You an also do...

```
days.map!{|day| day == "jueves" ? "thursday" : day}
```

m-p's answer will replace the first occurrence, this will replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 4):

```
days[3] = "thursday"
```

Unless you want something more dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

```
days[days.index("jueves")] = "thursday"
```

?